# Subtyping and type parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, variance

I'm new to Scala, and currently learning about type paramaters in Scala where I came across the following scenario.

Assume I have 2 classes `A` and `B`, where `B` is a subtype of `A`.

```
class A {
...
}

class B extends A {
...
}
```

So I can say `B <: A`.

Does this also mean `List[B] <: List[A]`?

Comment: It is also well explained it the Scala courses from Martin Odersky (https://class.coursera.org/progfun-2012-001/lecture/83), but you'll have to enroll, but it's worth it :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the case of List, it `B <: A` does indeed imply `List[B] <: List[A]`, because List's type parameter is covariant. Making a type parameter covariant means that it can only show up in covariant positions in the definition of List, i.e. it can only show up as the return type of a method, not as the type of a parameter. The "tour of Scala" contains a section about [variance](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/129). Wikipedia also has a good [article about variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_%28computer_science%29). The three options for the variance of a type parameter are:

- invariance: `C[A]` is not a subtype of `C[B]`, no matter what the relationship between `A` and `B` is. Examples of this are mutable data structures such as arrays.
- covariance: `B <: A` implies `C[B] <: C[A]`. Examples are immutable data structures or the return type of functions.
- contravariance: `A <: B` implies `C[B] <: C[A]`. For example, Functions are contravariant in the types of their parameters.